# Phonegap_ "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH

Tags: git, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I know this question has been asked but i am really confused.
I have installed git and my PATH variable looks like this

```
%Path%;%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;
C:\Users\Miserda\nodejs\npm;C:\android-sdk-win;
C:\Users\Miserda\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

and i don't understand how doesn't it recognize it??

Comment: Jsut to be sure, could you remove the space between the last '`;`' and the `C:\` in your `%PATH%`?

Comment: Just did , seems to do the trick but now i get this error

[error] Command failed: fatal: could not create work tree dir .: No such file or dir
ectory

Comment: It worked! i made that directory manually. 
Put your comment as an answer so i can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue seemed to come from the space between the ';' and the 'C:\' in the PATH

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin 
                                   ^
```

Removing allows for git command to be recognized.